# DataTemplate inside ListView (with VirtualizingStackPanel) causing StackOverflow

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol, virtualizingstackpanel

I have a data type, `Metadata`, that contains a file path to either a video or an image. I'm attempting to use a `DataTemplate` to display that data type. There's going to be thousands of these objects, so I'm also using an `ListView` + `VirtualizingStackPanel` (well, actually, a `VirtualizingWrapPanel`, but I switch to the StackPanel to make sure it wasn't a bug with the WrapPanel code) to attempt to virtualize those elements.

Here's the XAML code for the ItemsControl:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="ListBlock"
            Margin="5"
            Background="Transparent">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

The code for the DataTemplate (inside `App.xaml`:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type media:Metadata}">
    <controls:MediaContainer/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The code for the MediaContainer:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <Border x:Name="Outline">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            <Image x:Name="DisplayImage" />
            <MediaElement x:Name="DisplayVideo" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind:

```cs
// Called On Loaded

Metadata data = (Metadata)DataContext;
Uri uri = new(data.FilePath);

if (data.FileType == FileType.Video) 
{
    DisplayVideo = new()
    {
        Source = uri,
        Height = data.Height,
        Width = data.Width
    };
}
else 
{
    BitmapImage source = new(uri);
    DisplayImage = new() 
    { 
        Source = data.FileType == FileType.Gif ? null : source,
        Height = data.Height,
        Width = data.Width
    };

    if (data.FileType == FileType.Gif) 
    {
        // more code
    }
}
```

I then assign a list of `Metadata` as the `ItemsSource` on Loaded for another window

```
Loaded += (_, _) => {
    ListBlock.ItemsSource = storage.CurrentAlbum.Media;
    // Logging ListBlock.Items.Count shows the correct number of items              
};
```

I was under the impression that this is all I'd have to do, but when executing the code with the Data Template, I get a StackOverflow exception (executing the code *without* the Data Template does not cause the exception).

I've insured that there's no recursive code within the UserControl that I've created for the template, and I never create the control manually (ie. the only thing to constructs it is WPF). I've included the entire script below, just in case it's pertinent, however.

```
public Border OutlineElement { get => Outline; }
public Image ImageElement { get => DisplayImage; }
public MediaElement VideoElement { get => DisplayVideo; }
public Metadata Metadata { get; private set; } 

public event EventHandler OnSelect;

private bool isSelected = false;

public MediaContainer() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (_, _) => Load();
}

public void Select() {
    if (isSelected) {
        Outline.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        isSelected = false;
    } else {
        Outline.BorderBrush = Configs.OUTLINE_COLOR;
        isSelected = true;
        OnSelect?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

private void Load() {
    Metadata data = (Metadata)DataContext;
    Uri uri = new(data.FilePath);
    Metadata = data;

    (double height, double width) = Scale(data);

    Outline.Width = width + (Configs.OUTLINE_WIDTH * 2);
    Outline.Height = height + (Configs.OUTLINE_WIDTH * 2);

    if (data.FileType == FileType.Video) {
        DisplayVideo = new() {
            Source = uri,
            Height = height,
            Width = width,
            LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual,
            Volume = 0
        };

        DisplayVideo.MouseEnter += (o, e) => PeekVideo(o, e, true);
        DisplayVideo.MouseLeave += (o, e) => PeekVideo(o, e, false);

        DisplayVideo.Pause();
    } else {
        BitmapImage source = new(uri);
        DisplayImage = new() {
            Source = data.FileType == FileType.Gif ? null : source,
            Height = height,
            Width = width
        };

        if (data.FileType == FileType.Gif) {
            ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(DisplayImage, source);
            ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(DisplayImage, System.Windows.Media.Animation.RepeatBehavior.Forever);
        }
    }

    async void PeekVideo(object o, MouseEventArgs e, bool isEntering) {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) { return; }

        DisplayVideo.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

        if (!isEntering) {
            DisplayVideo.Pause();
            DisplayVideo.Position = new(0);
            return;
        }

        await Task.Delay(250);

        if (!DisplayVideo.IsMouseOver) { return; }

        DisplayVideo.Volume = 0;
        DisplayVideo.Play();
    }
    static (double, double) Scale(Metadata meta) {
        double _height = meta.Height;
        double _width = meta.Width;

        if (meta.Height != Configs.HEIGHT && meta.Height > 0) {
            double scale = Configs.HEIGHT / meta.Height;
            _height = meta.Height * scale;
            _width = meta.Width * scale;
        }

        return new(_height, _width);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code behind of your UserControl seems to be located in its constructor. Be aware that the DataContext property is not yet set there. Move the code to a Loaded event handler.

Comment: @EldHasp *"It is also VERY bad to use Code Behind. *" - Please stop spreading this utter nonsense. You are making things worse for every beginner. Code-behind is not "very bad"! It's just C# and partial classes. How do you implement a for-loop without code-behind? This can only lead to stupid design choices.

Comment: When you want to use UI virtualization, then use the `ListBox´ or `ListView`. Your current code does not enable UI virtualization. To help with your problem you should show *all* the necessary and relevant code that is required to reproduce your unwanted behavior. For example, it's not clear how you initialize the ItemsControl. If your ItemsControl is empty, then you obviously are not initializing it properly or you have erroneous code that prevents the ItemsControl from initializing properly. Have you tried to run your code without a DataTemplate?

Comment: Running the application in debug mode can also provide useful information via the Output window. Especially when you increase the XAML error trace level in the Visual Studio debugger settings.

Comment: @BionicCode I switched to a Listview and ran it w/o the DataTemplate, and it works. But switching the DataTemplate back on caused a StackOverflow exception. I updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StackOverflowException` exception was a very valuable hint.

It looks the issue stems from the nested `ContentPresenter` inside the `UserControl`.

```xml
<UserControl>
    <Border x:Name="Outline">
        <Grid>
            <!-- This is the problematic element, and doesn't make sense -->
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>

            <Image x:Name="DisplayImage" />
            <MediaElement x:Name="DisplayVideo" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

It's not apparent what the `ContentPresenter` is for.

However, when the `ItemsControl` loads a `Metadata` item:

1. The `DataTemplate` for the `Metadata` type is loaded.
   Now, the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` is the `Metadata` item.
2. This `Metadata` item is inherited as `DataContext` to the `UserControl` that is inside this `DataTemplate`.
3. The `DataContext` of the `UserControl` (still the same `Metadata` item) again is inherited to the `DataContext` of the internal elements. One of those is the `ContentPresenter`.
4. The `ContentPresenter` binds its `ContentPresenter.Content` property to the current `DataContext`, the `Metadata` item, per `Binding` declaration.
5. The value returned from the `Bindig` and assigned to the `ContentPresenter.Content` property will force the `ContentPresenter` to try loading a `DataTemplate` itself for the current `Content` value.
6. The `ContentPresenter` finds the implicit `DataTemplate` for the content value (the `Metadata` item) and applies it.
7. Loading the `DataTemplate` will also create a new `UserControl` instance because this `UserControl` is a child of the `DataTemplate`.
8. The process starts at 1) again ==> infinite loop ==> exhausts stack memory ==> `StackOverflowException` is thrown.

Without knowing the purpose of the nested `ContentPresenter` you could define the `DataTemplate` as an explicit template by assigning it an explicit key. This way the nested `ContentPresenter` can't load it implicitly:

**App.xaml**
Define the `DataTemplate` as explicit

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemDataTemplate" 
              DataType="{x:Type media:Metadata}">
    <controls:MediaContainer/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
Assign the `DataTemplate` explicitly to the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` property.

Note, because the `ListBox` and `ListView` both support UI virtualization by default, you no longer have to override the default `ItemsPanelTemplate`: it's already a `VirtualizingStackPanel`!

```xml
<ListView x:Name="ListBlock"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemDataTemplate"}>
</ListView>
```

Now the infinite loop is broken because the `ContentPresenter` that is nested into the `UserControl` no longer finds a `DataTemplate` as the `DataTemplate` is now explicit (registered with an explicit `x:Key`).

Now you should be able to understand the issue better.
How to finally solve it depends on the purpose of the nested `ContentPresenter`. Usually, you don't set the `ContentPresenter.Content` property explicitly. The value is implicitly assigned by the framework - if the `ContentPresenter` is placed inside a `ContentControl` (and a `UserControl` is a `ContentControl`). But most importantly, binding the `ContentPresenter` to the `DataTemplate.DataContext` is giving you the issues - and doesn't make *any* sense.

Instead of making the `DataTemplate` explicit I highly recommend fixing the layout of the `UserControl`.